# Compare the SUM() of two columns from different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have these two queries:

```
-- Getting the total no. of items CLAIMED for a sales order
SELECT SUM(qty_claimed) As 'total_items_claimed'
FROM so_claim_item
WHERE sales_order_id = 1;

-- Getting the total no. of items originally ORDERED for a sales order
SELECT SUM(quantity) As 'total_items_ordered'
FROM sales_order_item
WHERE sales_order_id = 1;

-- If the sums of the two columns are equal, return 1 or true. 
-- Else, return 0 or false.
```

I need to compare the sums of those two columns from different tables to see if a sales order is complete or not.

If 1 is returned, meaning the no. of items claimed is equal to no. of items ordered, it means the sales order is completed.
Otherwise, the sales order remains unclaimed/partially claimed.

This is by far the best solution I can think of, **but I wish to write it in a single query** that will only return one value, if that's possible. But if you have better suggestions, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `CASE`?

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN
       (
           SELECT SUM(qty_claimed) AS 'total_items_claimed'
           FROM so_claim_item
           WHERE sales_order_id = 1
       ) =
       (
           SELECT SUM(quantity) AS 'total_items_ordered'
           FROM sales_order_item
           WHERE sales_order_id = 1
       ) THEN
           1
       ELSE
           0
   END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use having as below:

```
    SELECT SUM(qty_claimed) As 'total_items_claimed'
    FROM so_claim_item A
    WHERE A.sales_order_id = 1    
    having SUM(qty_claimed) =(SELECT SUM(quantity) As 'total_items_ordered') 
                     FROM sales_order_item B
                     WHERE B.sales_order_id = 1)
```

Here is more informations about [having](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this by putting the values in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT (sci.total_items_claimed = soi.total_items_ordered) as is_same
FROM (SELECT SUM(qty_claimed) As total_items_claimed
      FROM so_claim_item
      WHERE sales_order_id = 1
     ) sci CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(quantity) As total_items_ordered
      FROM sales_order_item
      WHERE sales_order_id = 1
     ) soi;
```

You can also do this with subqueries in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT ( (SELECT SUM(qty_claimed) As total_items_claimed
          FROM so_claim_item
          WHERE sales_order_id = 1
         ) =
         (SELECT SUM(quantity) As total_items_ordered
          FROM sales_order_item
          WHERE sales_order_id = 1
         )
       ) as is_same;
```